# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration while deleting the key from the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to delete a key from the dictionary. While doing I got RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

```
myDict = {'A': [('Yes!', '8'), ('Ok!', '0')], 'B': [('No!', '2')]}
    for key in myDict.keys():
        if 'A' in key:
            #print ('exist')
            del myDict['A']
    print(myDict)
```

Desired out

```
{'B': [('No!', '2')]}
```

Comment: Don't add/delete items from something (list, set, dictionary) while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict` comprehension to filter out:

```
{k: v for k, v in myDict.items() if 'A' not in k}
```

Output:

```
{'B': [('No!', '2')]}
```